# Showing a graph with PCA selected features in Random Forest Model

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, pca

So I created a Random Forest Model like so:

```
incr_pca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=40)
Xtrain_pca = incr_pca.fit_transform(X_train)
Xtest_pca = incr_pca.transform(X_test)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced')
rfc.fit(Xtrain_pca,y_train)
y_pred_default = rfc.predict(Xtest_pca)
```

Then I plotted the 20 most important features like so:

```
feat_importances = pd.Series(rfc.feature_importances_)
feat_importances.nlargest(20).plot(kind='barh')
feat_importances
```

This gives me only the column indexes of the features, how can I show their names?